# Ubuntu Software not opening?

Tags: 21.04, ubuntu-store

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux. When I try to open Ubuntu Software it shows it's loading, but after a few seconds it stops and nothing happens. When I run `snap-store` in the terminal it says:

```
/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error:
/snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0:
undefined symbol: atk_plug_set_child"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
snap remove snap-store

snap install snap-store --candidate
```

could be a workaround