# Ubuntu Software is not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center

I am not able to open Ubuntu Software, even after I restart/shut down my machine.

Comment: see this answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1344701/1314523 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store/1344697#1344697

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)